# Why don't TypeScript routes work for me? In the editor it does not give an error, but when running it does

Tags: typescript, server, backend

This is the error:
I the editor I don't get the error

```bash
Error: Cannot find module '@/controllers/Auth/login'
Require stack:
- /home/michael/Documents/repos/work/la-victoria-admin/server/src/routes/auth/index.ts
- /home/michael/Documents/repos/work/la-victoria-admin/server/src/routes/index.ts
- /home/michael/Documents/repos/work/la-victoria-admin/server/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/home/michael/Documents/repos/work/la-victoria-admin/server/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    ...
```

the file with problem, the route it's ok:

```
import login from '@/controllers/Auth/login';
import register from '@/controllers/Auth/register';

import type { IReply } from '@lib/shared/interfaces';
import type {
  DoneFuncWithErrOrRes,
  FastifyInstance,
  RegisterOptions,
} from 'fastify';

export default function auth(
  fastify: FastifyInstance,
  _: RegisterOptions,
  done: DoneFuncWithErrOrRes,
) {
  fastify.post<{ Reply: IReply }>('/login', login);
  fastify.post<{ Reply: IReply }>('/register', register);

  done();
}
```

and my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@/": [
        "./src/"
      ],
      "@lib/shared/*": [
        "../libs/shared/src/*"
      ],
      "@lib/shared": [
        "../libs/shared/src/"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I use a lib folder to share interface into the frontend and the backennd code, this the structure:

[image]

Comment: I think that is beacause I use ES6, but in tscofnig is set as commonjs. Tihs solve the error, but i get another error that is:
```

> server@0.0.1 dev
> ts-node src/index.ts

TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/michael/Documents/repos/work/la-victoria-admin/server/src/index.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:143:22)
    ````